# How best to translate "a something called *name*" ?

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot, oral

Today I asked a man for directions to a restaurant called Jake's by saying *Je cherche un restaurant qui s'appelle Jake's ?*

Afterwards I immediately began to second-guess my choice of phrasing. He understood me, but was it really right? If I want to say "an [object] called [name]," can I use *qui s'appelle* ? Does that work in all cases? For example, are all of the following valid?

Je cherche...

- un restaurant qui s'appelle Jake's
- un chat qui s'appelle Jake
- un homme qui s'appelle Jake
- un endroit qui s'appelle Jake's Hill
- un parc qui s'appelle Jake's Park

Is *qui se nomme* equally valid, or is it more formal? What about *dont le nom est...* ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is : you were right and chose the best natural-sounding one. And it fits equally well in all your listed examples, places, people or animals.

Here you could alternatively have skipped the verb part with *Je recherche le restaurant "Jake's"*, but it's the second-best choice to me, yours is clearer.

All your three variants `(qui s'appelle / qui se nomme / dont le nom est)` exist and mean the same, but the levels of formalness (?) are different. "*Qui se nomme*" or "*dont le nom est*" are indeed more formal.

Last thing, *se nommer* is mostly used when refering to people rather than things, so it would be the only variant slightly odd here.